# xml modification using perl

Tags: perl, xml-twig

This is my sample xml file (snipped version of deployment plan for weblogic application).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment-plan>
  <application-name>ear-my-service</application-name>
  <variable-definition>
    <variable>
      <name>characteristics</name>
      <value>myTestEAR</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>Url</name>
      <value>ABC</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>time</name>
      <value>300</value>
    </variable>
  </variable-definition>
</deployment-plan>
```

I want to update the value when the name is characteristics. I looked around and put together this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $data = shift ||die $!;

my $t= XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        q{project[string(name) =~ /\bcharacteristics\b/]/value} => \&value,
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$t->parsefile( $data );
$t->print;

sub value {
    my ($twig, $value) = @_;
    $value->set_text("myTestEAR_Modified");
}
```

However, it doesn't change the value to myTestEAR_Modified. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag name in the XML is `variable`, not `project`, replace it in the condition (`q{variable[string(name)...`) and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mirod, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: Also, how could I add more than one checks? Example, if name is equal to characteristics, set the value to myTestEAR_Modified and if name is equal to Url, set the value to UrlModified?

Comment: you could either have several conditions, each with its own handler, or just set a handler on variable, and update the value (in  `$variable->first_child( 'value')`) depending on the name (in `$variable->first_child( 'name')`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the latter and it worked. One last question - instead of printing the xml with the replacements, I would like to edit the original xml in line. How could that be done?